# What's the meaning of -i in ssh?

Tags: command-line, ssh

What does the `-i` tag add to a command such as:

```
ssh -i path-to-pem-file ubuntu@ip-address
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the manpage:

```
-i identity_file
             Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public
             key authentication is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/identity for
             protocol version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa,
             ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and ~/.ssh/id_rsa for protocol version 2.
             Identity files may also be specified on a per-host basis in the 
             configuration file.  It is possible to have multiple -i options
             (and multiple identities specified in configuration files).  
             If no certificates have been explicitly specified by the
             CertificateFile directive, ssh will also try to load certificate 
             information from the filename obtained by appending -cert.pub to 
             identity filenames.
```

Basically, it's telling the SSH command to look at the key file you need for authentication on the destination server. If you use key authentication and were provided a certificate, this is where you want to specify it. If you use normal password auth, ignore that option.

Also, for the future, it's easier to Google things like this. You'll spend less effort, and you'll get an answer faster.

Comment: fwiw, googled and this is top answer, so, thanks for all of us in the future.

Answer (score 5):

From the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1)

> -i    identity_file
>
> ```
>    Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public
>    key authentication is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/identity for
>    protocol version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa,
>    ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and ~/.ssh/id_rsa for protocol version 2.
>    Identity files may also be specified on a per-host basis in the
>    configuration file.  It is possible to have multiple -i options
>    (and multiple identities specified in configuration files).  If
>    no certificates have been explicitly specified by the
>    CertificateFile directive, ssh will also try to load certificate
>    information from the filename obtained by appending -cert.pub to
>    identity filenames.
> ```